# Change all select option text to uppercase, Jquery or CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

Having the following country option list and displayed texts are capitalized;

```
<select id="countrySelect"..>
    <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
    <option value="JP">Japan</option>
    ...
</select>
```

How can those all display-texts be upprecase like **SINGAPORE**, **JAPAN**, and so on?

Any `JQuery` or `CSS` way is appreciated, and which one is better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use CSS:

```css
#countrySelect {
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

A CSS solution is better because the browser does all the work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Using Jquery, You can use `.text()` or `.html()` along with its callback function to set value in uppercase:

```
$('#countrySelect option').text(function(i,oldtext){
  return oldtext.toUpperCase();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t13yz4ou/)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want jQuery use toUpperCase()

```
    $('#countrySelect option').each(function(){
      $(this).text($(this).text().toUpperCase());
    });
```

Working fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/Jm9k6/

Answer (score 0):

use css

```css
#countrySelect {text-transform:uppercase;}
```

Comment: ...because in most cases CSS is faster and you rarely find users that disable CSS but a lot who disable JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, use jQuery to uppercase with css:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#countrySelect').css('text-transform','uppercase');
});
```